# Why is it so difficult to upgrade a website using Drupal? Any advice?

Tags: website, drupal

I'm currently trying to upgrade my company's website which uses Drupal 4.3 to Drupal 6.15. This has been exceptionally difficult to do so far.

I realize I could simply start a new site using 6.15 and rebuild the website from scratch but there is too much data to have to import by doing things that way.

Has anybody done a similar upgrade and had success without breaking all the modules they've added and what not?

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Because the first thing many web frameworks do is create a micro-economy of web developers which, if it were easy to do, would not have jobs.

Seriously, you're talking about not one but two major version upgrades.  Chances are many years of development have occurred between those, and web systems move very fast.  They are not as static as a single-author system may be.  Even Rails, which I find to be TRIVIAL to migrate to later versions, is still some amount of work when I am not the author of the system.

I'm not saying I write better code, but the sites I author are updated frequently enough that version drift is a small, incremental change rather than a flag day update.

Most people just rebuild from scratch.  We even do this with our OS machines now, it's just faster and safer.

Comment: I've managed to get it to v5 but v6.15 still seems like a distant dream.

Thanks for taking the time to write out a thoughtful  response. Often times I fail to think about things from a developer's perspective.

I'm hoping to get this upgraded so that I don't have to ask the developers to recreate all of the pages as they are already busy enough.